# Terraform 0.12 include statement only if condition applies

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create an aws_iam_policy_document by adding a few statements but it fails because "arn:aws:iam::${var.account_number}:role/audit_${var.deployment_identifier" role does not exist when I first call this process:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "kms_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "Enable root access to kms key"

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["${var.root_role}"]
    }

    actions = [
      "kms:Create*",
      "kms:Describe*"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid = "Allow encryption access for specific roles"

    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = "["arn:aws:iam::${var.account_number}:role/audit_${var.deployment_identifier}"]"
    }

    actions = [
      "kms:Encrypt"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

The thing is, I need that last statement there because it will be needed a step further ahead.

How can I check if the role exists when I first run through this process, and if it does not exist then it must not add the statement?

Comment: Are you defining your IAM role somewhere else in your Terraform code? If so, you could use a `depends_on` argument to cause Terraform to create the role before creating this policy document.

Comment: I am, but in a different module

Comment: Since this is TF 0.12, `depends_on` won't work for dependencies within modules unfortunately. But, if you can have the other module output the role name, you can use that output in the `identifiers` field in the `aws_iam_policy_document` which will cause Terraform to create the role first and then this policy document.

Comment: The `aws_iam_policy_document` data source just creates a policy document in Terraform's memory, so it shouldn't matter when that happens as long as all of the data you interpolate is available. I assume there's some other downstream resource referring to this which is the one failing; can you update your question to include the configuration for that resource too, and also the full error message you saw when you tried to apply it?